# How to create dynamic rows field in custom Ui component form

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, custom-field, dynamic-rows

I want to create field in custom ui form to add dynamic row and delete that row..

I know how to add dynamic row field in STORE > Configuration but I don't know how to add in UI component form.
[image: Custom dynamic row field]

Then I want to store this custom field data in custom table.

Anyone knows then please help...

Comment: did you have answer for this?